# rails css How to place two button in a line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm rails beginner.
I want to make two button that are placed in a line.

How can I put the button correctly on a line of the table?

Two buttons:

```
<%= button_to "empty Cart", @cart, method: :delete %>
 <%= submit_tag "Delete item" %>
```

my view
    
        
            <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_carts_path, method: :delete do %>

```
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "checkbox_size_sm"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td class = "image">ITEM</td>
                    <td class = "title"> </td>
                    <td>PRICE</td>
                </tr>
                <% @cart.line_items.order(created_at: :desc).each do |item| %>

                <tr>
                    <td><%= check_box_tag "item_ids[]", item.id %></td>

                    <td class = "image"><%= image_tag item.product.item, size: "100" %>
                    </td>
                    <td class = "title" id = "td_align_middle">
                        <%= item.product.title %><br>
                        <%= item.product.brand %>
                    </td>
                    <td id = "td_align_middle"><%= item.product.price %></td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>



            </tbody>    
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan = "4" class="total_price" >
                        Total Price <strong>  <%= @cart.cart_total_price %> </strong>   
                        </td>               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan ="4" class="al-r">
                    <%= button_to "empty Cart", @cart, method: :delete %> <%= submit_tag "Delete item" %>       
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Help me..

Answer (score 0):

wrap those buttons in a div, set the div to float left and overflow hidden
add hose two buttons in div with class divname and in css file add below style to
`div.divname button { float:left; margin-right:10px; }`